# Normalisation - Table Structure

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling

I have this table which I want to design the table structure for in 3NF.

```
Patient ID  Name   Address   Mobile  DOB        Clinic   Consultant  Appointment  Cancelled
01          John   1 Road    0777    10/10/1992 FRAC1    Dr Test     01/01/2021      Yes
02          Tony   2 Road    0789    10/09/1995 EYE01    Dr Test two 02/02/2021
```

Which I have split out into three separate tables:

Patient Table

- Patient ID
- Name
- Address
- Mobile
- DOB

Clinic Table

- Clinic
- Consultant

Appointment Table

- Appointment ID (PK)
- Patient ID (FK)
- Clinic (FK)
- Consultant
- Appointment
- Cancelled

Have I done this correctly? I am doing practice for a university assignment on data models.

Comment: I suspect you need to think a little more about your "Clinic" table.  Does it follow correctly that your "Clinic" table should have multiple rows for the same clinic (but for each different consultant that may work at that clinic)?  Similarly, is it possible that the same consultant might see patients at more than one clinic?  These are the sorts of questions that should drive your decisions about data structure

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks, there may be more than one consultant at each clinic. A consultant will only be based at one clinic. How would this change my structure? Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Think about the key principles of 3NF.  Think about the decision that you have about Patients - why is there a "Patient" table with a specific ID (which would be the patient key)?  What do you think is different about a Clinic or Consultant, compared with a Patient, that would mean clinics and consultants wouldn't have their own "key" tables?  If you don't believe that clinics and consultants need their own "key" tables, why not?

Comment: Thanks, I have added in your recommended on having separate tables for clinics and consultants. To my knowledge within the appointment table, I would have an Appointment ID as the Primary key and the following foreign keys:  Patient_ID (Foreign Key - Patient Information Table) Clinic ID(Foreign Key - Clinic Table) Consultant_ID (Foreign Key - Consultant Table) as well as the appointment date. In theory is this accurate?

Comment: That does make more sense.  The only remaining thing, as per @Gordon Linoff's suggestion, is whether you would have a table to maintain the relationship between a Clinic and a Consultant.  You said previously that a consultant would only be based at a single clinic .... so, thinking beyond just the table structure and into, let's say, an application that would be used to create appointments, how would you present - to the application user - the list of available consultants, for a particular clinic, when booking an appointment?  A table holding that relationship would be useful in that regard

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  You seem to have the following basic entities:

- Patients
- Clinics
- Consultants
- Appointments

You then have the following relationships:

- WORKSAT: Consultant, Clinic
- APPOINTMENT:  Patient, Consultant, Clinic, Time

This is a basic look at the structure.  There are refinements:

- You might want a calendar table for the time.
- You might want a slowly changing dimension to map addresses and mobile numbers to patients.